# Update entire location.pathName when using history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a website that loads all of my content into my main index.php. I am trying to make it use clean URLS.

Example: http://www.host.com/home

This URL will load home.php into the index.php. I am updating my history by using history.pushstate() but on some pages I want to have a more in depth URL.

Example: http://www.host.com/forum/topicName

This will load the forum page into the index and get the topic name from mySQL and display it. But from here if I click one of my nav buttons the URL will end up looking like this...

Example: http://www.host.com/forum/home

I want it to clean out that /forum and just leave the /home here is some of my code so far.

```
function myNav(whereTo)
{   

    window.history.pushState(null, null, whereTo);

    var toLoad = 'pages/'+whereTo+'.php';

    $('#mainContent').load(toLoad);
}
```

This is what I am using right now as a quick fix I was hoping there was a better way.

```
if(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') != 0)
        window.location.pathname = whereTo;
    else
        window.history.pushState(null, null, whereTo);
```

Comment: you can use relative urls, like "/home" and "/forum/topicName". make sure the page works upon refresh btw.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dandavis. I guess adding a / to the begining of the URL in

`window.history.replaceState(stateObj, title, URL);`

replaces the entire pathName as opposedin to the way I was doing it and just adding the page name.